Carbon seatpost stuck due to damaged grub screw
I have an Orbea Orca 2024 with Di2 and the grub screw for adjusting seat height has potential thread damage and it won't come out. The bike mechanic explained that the reason the grub screw went so deep was because the Seatpost wedge had fallen inside the seat tube and the screw was tightened without the wedge resulting in the screw damaging the seat post and potentially the screw's threads.
The mechanic also explained to me that in case to remove the screw, the seat post needs to be cut.
I was wondering what's the efficient way to cut and remove the stuck screw and both parts of the seat post?



I would definitely try a screw extractor before doing any cutting.

@DavidW, But if the screw's thread is damaged, it would also damage the thread in the frame. That would not allow the new screw to fit.

So the hex key head is still fine but the screw spins freely and won’t come out when you turn counterclockwise? Or how do you know about the thread damage? In any case I can’t see how screwing it out would cause more damage.

I don't know how the frame thread would be damaged unless the screw is cross-threaded, and I don't think backing it out would make that any worse.  If you're not positive the frame is damaged I would still try to get the screw out first.

@Michael, from the current position, I can screw it in a few turns (potentially poking the seat tube) and unscrew a few turns, but it won't unscrew beyond that. So the tip of the screw threads are damaged (according to the bike mechanic)

Have a look at ways to remove a stuck seat post - effectively this is what you are dealing with, Lots of questions in this site, mostly covered by this https://www.sheldonbrown.com/stuck-seatposts.html

@mattnz, The seat post is not stuck to the frame, I can rotate it by a few degrees in both directions and can also move it up and down by 2-3mm up and down. It's the grub screw that's blocking the way and I am unable to remove the screw. The screw has probably damaged the carbon seat post as well because I can move the seat a little bit in all directions

I call it stuck.... #13 in the linked page will work.

@mattnz, yes #13 could potentially work. Let's say we carefully cut around the seat post so that the Di2 batter is not damaged, then how to get the battery out? Because the battery is attached to the seat post from the bottom.
